# Using nodejs routes to show each users page

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm somewhat familiar on url rewriting. On instagram if I wanted to go to someone's specific page it'd be instagram.com/username/. I just set up routes for each page and I use firebase firestore to all the data. When a user clicks on the person's name,  their username is added to the url but of course, there's an error saying that's not a page.
This is the routes code

```
    const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const explore = require("./public/explore.js")

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/welcome.html'));
});
app.get('/ask', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/ask.html'));
});
app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/contact.html'));
});
app.get('/events', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/events.html'));
});
app.get('/explore', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/explore.html'));
});
app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/form.html'));
});
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/login.js'));
});
app.get('/reset', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/reset.html'));
});
app.get('/settings', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/settings.html'));
});
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/signup.html'));
});
app.listen(3333);
```

At the top of the routes.js file, I required the explore.js file that lists displays all  the user's profile pics along with their names and an onclick that adds their username to the page so I can also use the functions I have in that file in the routes file.

I've been stuck on this for a while but I know I should use some kind of get method. I have no idea how to get the template I made to display along with making each user's page viewable. Any guidance? Thanks

Comment: What's an example of a URL with the user's name in it that you want to respond to?

Comment: sitename.com/username/. that format

Comment: `http://sitename.com/someusername/` is generally not advised because then usernames all compete or conflict with your other top level URLs such as `/login` and `/contact`.  You could do `http://sitename.com/user/someusername/` if you wanted because then that scopes the username to the `http://sitename.com/user` prefix.  Also, note it's pretty hard to help very productively if you're taking 3 days to answer simple questions about your post.

Comment: Makes sense, I waited for the other guy to respond then assumed nobody else responded. I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/users/:userid', function (req, res) {
 //your logic to show profile
});
```

You should try something like the above. I am assuming your route is **/users** and you want to load each user under that profile.

E.g. HTML code that calls the above route.

```
<html>
 <body>
    <a href="/users/121212">User 1</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was pretty clear but I have 2 quick questions. I have the specific user as user.uid so  should it be app.get('/users/' + user.uid, function (req, res) {
 //your logic to show profile
});                                                                                                                                                My 2nd is for the html, would <a href="/users/121212">User 1</a> be added to my onclick to take them to that person's page? I'll mark  ur response as an answer after you clarify the last 2 questions